# Canon MX340 scanner put »copy« watermark into PDF

Tags: scanner, canon-pixma

I have tried to scan my master's certificate with a Canon MX340 print-scan-copy-fax machine. In the PDF, I see a ridiculous »copy« watermark embedded into the image:

[image]

When one takes a look at the document that I scanned, it has an »original« watermark:

[image]

This is the first time that I have seen this, so I would presume that it recognizes the »original« watermark and then marks the scanned version as such.

When I send this PDF to somebody, it is automatically clear that this is not the original paper version. This »copy« watermark will make it look like I have lost my original certificate and would now have to work with a university supplied copy.

Is there some way to turn off this “feature”?

Comment: I have this printer/scanner and I have never seen it automatically put "Copy" on any document.  Are you using another program to access the scanner, or are you having the scanner create the PDF directly (such as to a USB driver or network location)?

Comment: I let it store the PDF document directly to a USB drive. There is no additional software involved, just the printer-scanner machine.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking the same, until I tried to obstruct part of the watermark to stop the scanner from being able to detect the watermark. I would have done several scans with different areas obstructed and re-merged them later.

Only when I saw that the "Kopie Copy" watermark was perfectly cut off at the start of the obstruction the penny dropped.

If you hold the paper under a bright light, you can see that the "Kopie Copy" watermark is a feature of the paper itself. Including the hideous typeface of course.